# The Riddle of the Temple

Tags: riddle

You enter an old temple, from a long-dead religion. Before you, in front of a pile of riches, stands a statue of a creature made of a mineral dark as night: a woman's head, a lion's body, an eagle's wings outstretched to block your path. In front of it, a plaque written in old language -- but thankfully, you thought ahead to bring along a Universal Translator Mk. 7000! The plaque reads as follows:

> Make a promise, if you'd like. But keep your word, else I may strike.
>
> A set of words may do you well, a phrase with which you cast this spell.
>
> Letters all, but not once each, this phrase to me you must beseech.

What do you say, to get your reward?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume we are supposed to say

> SPHINX OF BLACK QUARTZ, JUDGE MY VOW

which is

> a famous pangram (but has two Os and therefore doesn't have just one of each letter)

although

> this is pretty darn weird since evidently this thing's original language is not English

and

> it seems like one could come up with any number of "not once each" pangrams that mention making and keeping promises, so this feels a bit too guess-what-I-was-thinking-y for my taste...

In case it's not obvious from the above,

> there are some hints embedded in the story leading to this *specific* famous pangram. Woman's head + lion's body + eagle's wings = sphinx; mineral dark as night = black quartz; "make a promise" -- "my vow"; "else I may strike" -- an invitation to "judge".

Comment: Nice job! Wasn't sure if it was too easy, or too hard, or just not a good riddle. Forcing a rhyme may have made it more annoying, though... Enjoy your virtual riches! (And a nice checkmark when it's reasonable!)

Comment: As I said, a bit too guess-what-I'm-thinking-y for my taste, but it did make me smile. (I see someone's downvoted you, but it wasn't me.)